# What causes this delay during page rendering after html loaded?

Tags: jquery-mobile, loading, pagespeed

I want to decrease the time where a jQuery Mobile site shows a blank page during pageload. Due to AdSense I had to include data-ajax="false", so there are no smooth transitions anymore and worse, the header disapears as something keeps the page from rendering during page load.

The timeline shows a significant delay after load of the html document and after loading all CSS/JS resources:

[image]

What could be the cause of this and would it be possible to eliminate this gap?

Comment: It looks like you have a filter applied to the monitoring tool.

Comment: There seems not to be a filter active. Chrom dev tools button "ALL" is selected.

Comment: HTML parsing and page rendering usually take some time with jQuery Mobile. I'll recommend the Timeline tool in Chrome, the one right beside the Network tool, which provides a lot more details.

Comment: Could you provide a URL so that we can test this? Or if not, it would be helpful to see the file types in the waterfall image above....

Comment: Yes, sure. This is the URL: http://m.findix.de/kleinanzeigen/immobilienmarkt